# Sort Rows By keeping rows with specific values first in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a query that lists up the work schedules for all days in a week and time with half hour increments.

```
SELECT ID,    
 CallCenterScheduleID As WorkScheduleID,    
 C.DayOfWeekID,    
 C.TimeOfDayID,   
 T.DisplayValue TimeDisplayName,  
 W.DayOfWeekName WeekDisplayName

FROM tblCallCenterCapacityDetail C  

INNER JOIN tblWeekDay W  
ON C.DayOfWeekID = W.DayOfWeekID  

INNER JOIN tblTimeOfDay T  
ON C.TimeOfDayID = T.TimeOfDayID  

WHERE CallCenterScheduleID = 75

ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN C.DayOfWeekID = 6 AND T.DisplayValue = '2:30 PM' THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END ASC
```

Above query presents this result

[image]

Required:

1. WeekDisplayName has 48 records for each day, like you see for Wednesday, you see first 19 records first, and rest of records appear at the end of result. I need to place all 48 records of a day together, and then 48 records for each succeeding day later on.
2. After Wednesday, Thursday's first record has time 12:00AM, I need to show the same time as it was selected for Wednesay. As you can see, Wednesday first record shown has time on 2:30 PM, but Row # 20 which relates to Thursday shows 12:00AM first. 
   I need to show time of 2:30PM for each of day in week.

Comment: I'm confused. You want all 48 rows for each day to be next to each other but the times start at 2:30PM So my question is in your example what should the next row after 11:30PM Wednesday? Where is 1:30PM supposed to go?

Comment: After 1130PM, we need to show records before 230 AM that were skipped for thr day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution to above problem is to partition the records based on Time, and then ordering based on preferred day's value.

Following query does the trick.

```
SELECT ID,    
 CallCenterScheduleID,    
 C.DayOfWeekID,    
 C.TimeOfDayID,   
 T.DisplayValue TimeDisplayName,  
 W.DayOfWeekName WeekDisplayName,
 row_number() 
    OVER(
        partition by C.DayOfWeekID 
        ORDER BY
        CASE 
            WHEN 
                T.DisplayValue = '2:30 PM' 
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END ASC
    ) AS ROWNUM

FROM tblCallCenterCapacityDetail C  

INNER JOIN tblWeekDay W  
ON C.DayOfWeekID = W.DayOfWeekID  

INNER JOIN tblTimeOfDay T  
ON C.TimeOfDayID = T.TimeOfDayID  

WHERE CallCenterScheduleID = 75

ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            C.DayOfWeekID = 1

        THEN 0

        ELSE 1
   END ASC
```

As each day had 48 records, so records for each day are grouped together and setting 2:30PM for each day as first record.

[image]